# Jquery empty results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

### Problem

I tried after submitting the form not redirect to email php. For that I used ajax and its somehow working however it's gives back empty result. I have problem with javascript but thats enough difficult to find for my beginner level. I tested to send email without ajax and it sending normally. But redirecting to empty page email.php

### HTML

```
<form method="POST" id="myForm" data-toggle="validator" action="email.php">
  <h2 class="section-heading">Свяжитесь с нами:</h2>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Имя:</label>
    <input style="background:none;" id="firstName" name="firtname" class="form-control" placeholder="Имя" required>
    <p id="p1"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Тема:</label>
    <input style="background:none;" id="subjectTheme" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Тема" required>
    <p id="p2"></p>
  </div>   
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Электронная почта:</label>
    <input style="background:none;" type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Электронная почта" required>
    <p class="help-block with-errors"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Сообщение:</label>
    <textarea style="background:none;" name="message" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" id="sendButton" class="btn btn-default"/>
</form>
```

### Javascript

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'email.php'
   });
   $('#myForm')[0].reset();
   alert("Success!");

})
```

### PHP

```
<?php

$to = 'test@mail.ru'; // Replace with your email

$subject = $_POST['subject']; // Replace with your $subject
$headers = 'From: ' . $_POST['email'];  

$message = 'Имя: ' . $_POST['firtname'] . "\n" .
           'Электронная почта: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\n" .
           'Тема: ' . $_POST['subject'] . "\n" .
           'Сообщение: ' . $_POST['message'];

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

Comment: `var data = $(this).serialize();
$.post($(this).attr("action"), data, function(response) { alert("success")});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the content of the form and move the alert and reset to the callback:

```
$('#myForm').on("submit",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post(
    $(this).attr("action"), 
    $(this).serialize(),
    function(response) { 
      alert("success");
      $('#myForm')[0].reset();
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Thank you sir! That is what I need!

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the informations through AJAX. And reset your form on AJAX success. You didn't do that now.
Should look like this:

```js
$('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); 
   var firstname = $('#firstName').val();
   var subject = $('#subjectTheme').val();
   var email = $('#email').val();
   var message = $('#message').val();
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'email.php',
        data: {firstname: firstname, subject: subject, email: email, message: message },
        success: function(){
           $('#myForm')[0].reset();
           alert("Success!");
        }
   });
})
```

Comment: No need to take each value. See my comment and answer

Comment: No need, but I think is better this way as he can choose what he sends through POST.

Comment: If the form works without ajax, it will work the same with, even after the form is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Your email.php file should send a status message to your ajax based on mail is sent or not. You should send your form data to email.php file.

your **script**

```
    $('#myForm').on("submit",function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'email.php',
        data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
        success: function(data) { 
          if(data == 'success') {
              alert('mail sent success');
              $('#myForm')[0].reset();
          } else {
              alert('failed');
          }
        }
   });
```

your **PHP**

```
<?php
...
...
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    $status = 'success';
} else {
    $status = 'failed';
}
die($status);

?>
```